# pytest fixture - get value and avoid error "Fixture 'X' called directly"

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I have updated pytest to 4.3.0 and now I need to rework test code since calling fixtures directly is deprecated.

I have an issue with fixtures used in an unittest.TestCase, how do I get the value returned from the fixture and not a reference to the function itself ?

Example :

```
@pytest.fixture
def test_value():
    return 1

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("test_value")
class test_class(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_simple_in_class(self):
        print(test_value)    # prints the function reference and not the value
        print(test_value())  # fails with Fixtures are not meant to be called directly

def test_simple(test_value):
    print(test_value)  # prints 1
```

How can I get test_value in the test_simple_in_class() method ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was a [big discussion on this](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/3950) already. You can read through that or refer to the [deprecation documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/deprecations.html#calling-fixtures-directly).

In your contrived example it seems this is the answer:

```
@pytest.fixture(name="test_value")
def test_simple_in_class(self):
    print(test_value())
```

However, I suggest checking the docs. The other example might be what you want. You can read the discussion I linked to for some of the reasoning. The debate got a bit heated though.

Answer (score 13):

The solution to my simple example if anyone is interested.

```
def my_original_fixture():
    return 1

@pytest.fixture(name="my_original_fixture")
def my_original_fixture_indirect():
    return my_original_fixture()

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("my_original_fixture")
class test_class(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_simple_in_class(self):
        print(my_original_fixture())

def test_simple(my_original_fixture):
    print(my_original_fixture)
```

Answer (score 0):

I came to the following solution, it's possible to import runtime_test_params somewhere where this is needed and use "parameterless" access. This requires no changes to the parameterless_function function API.

```
import pytest

runtime_test_params = {
    "runtime_param": ""
}

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True ,params=["fixture param 1", "fixture param 2"], scope="session")
def sample_fixture(request):
    runtime_test_params["runtime_param"] = request.param
    yield request.param


def parameterless_function():
    print(f"parameterless_function {runtime_test_params}")


def test_parameterless_function():
    parameterless_function()
```