# How to run a scoped function before all pytest fixtures of that scope?

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, pytest

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22627659/913098), asking the same about doing things before tests.

I need to do things before fixtures.

For example, I am setting up a dockerized environment, which I have to clean before building. To make things more complicated, I am using [this plugin](https://github.com/pytest-docker-compose/pytest-docker-compose#:%7E:text=This%20package%20contains%20a%20pytest,down%20after%20each%20test%20ends.) which defines fixtures I can't control or change, and I need something that comes before all fixtures (and does `docker-compose down` and other cleanup).

For example, when pytest starts, run the common per-session pre-step, then the fixtures, then the per-module pre-step, then the fixtures, and so on.

Is this a supported hook in pytest?

I couldn't find a relevant doc.

Comment: Have you checked the `sessionstart` / `sessionfinish` hooks?

Comment: @MrBeanBremen It works at the start of the session. Is there a clean way to use simple fixtures within that function? For example, `def my_name(): return "Gulzar"` can be required for initialization, and also as a fixture. I can extract a function, but that seems like overkill. Does something better exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @MrBean Bremen stated, [pytest_sessionstart](https://pytest.org/en/7.0.x/reference/reference.html?highlight=sessionstart#pytest.hookspec.pytest_sessionstart) does the trick.

An annoying problem with that, is I can't use fixtures inside (naturally), with `Argument(s) {'fixture_name'} are declared in the hookimpl but can not be found in the hookspec`

I tried to fix that with [pytest-dependency](https://pytest-dependency.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#basic-usage), but it doesn't seem to work on fixtures, only on tests.

I am left with the [hacky workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54887864/913098) to extract required data for `sessionstart` to functions, and call them in `sessionstart` as well as in similarly named fixtures.

It works, but it is ugly.

**Would accept a cleaner solution over this one**