# Pytest fixture to make specific fixtures available in marked tests

Tags: python, pytest

I'd like to have a pytest marker which would make specific fixtures autoused in any marked tests.

For example, in this instance the marker `baz` would make the fixture `foo` available in `test_one` without any additional syntax.

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def foo():
    return 'bar'


@pytest.mark.baz
def test_one():
    s = foo
    assert s == 'bar'
```

Comment: refer [@pytest.mark.usefixtures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54886692/pytest-fixture-get-value-and-avoid-error-fixture-x-called-directly), and there are ways defined there to achieve this.